# SharePoint 2010 Search not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have installed and configured SharePoint 2010 to run on the same box as the SQL Server its running from in Windows Server 2008 R2. Everything is working fine except the search. I have uploaded several documents and tagged several items (documents, tasks, announcements etc), however whenever I search the site using the defaul search, i get nothing returned no matter what i search on, I simply get "We did not find any results for [*search term*]". I know there is setup needed if you wish to use "FAST search", but do I have to do anything to get the standard default search to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on [SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/3531/950):

> After installing the system you need to configure your indexing job.
>
> 1. Navigate to CA > Service Applications > Search.
> 2. You will see a link to your Content Sources. If you edit that it will give you the opportunity to setup a schedule for both Full and Incremental indexing.
> 3. You can kick off a full crawl, once completed you will have results if everything is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It does work for people search too . if you edit this content source you will see sps protocol which is for user profiles .

Answer (score 0):

To make people search to work, in Central Administration > Manage Service Applications, make sure to provide a valid domain\user account as administrator in User Profile Service Application.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Chensformers answers, the account has to have "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers" enabled. They have to have it in the Administrators button, even if the Permissions is set to Full Control! Quite misleading.